# Combining multiple JS files

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small color management library. To improve the productivity of the process and the management of the code, I've divided the code into smaller components (files). Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Folder structure]

Files are added in the index.html file in the correct order and I can do tests just fine.

Now, I've been wondering how to put these into a single JS file. The straight-forward way would be to create a new file and add the components manually (copy/paste). But that would present problems. When doing future modifications, I'd have to either modify two files (one in the components and the final, merged file), or just create the final file again. I rather not do this.

This became a problem when I decided to divide the code into smaller parts. Normally, working on 2-3 parts is fine for making copy/paste for the final file. But now, there are 24 files, and I fear it'll increase over time. So I need a way to automate this merging process.

I can think of two approaches to solve this. I'll either use a tool that lets me access File System (PHP, PowerShell, etc.) and combine the components into one file, or using JavaScript, I can access the object itself (`color`) and output it (itself, methods, properties).

I don't know why, but I took the second approach. I've written a script that walks through the `color` object, lists its properties and methods, and outputs them using `Object.prototype.toString()` and `JSON.stringify()`. And later, I download it using `Blob`. This seems to work well. However, I don't know if this will present problems in the future that I can't overcome.

Is there a better way to handle this?

I also wonder how the big frameworks/libraries handle this. If I were to use a single file to write all the code, I'd have to work with 2k~ lines. No matter how well organized the code is, this looks scary. jQuery (10k~ lines), compared to mine, is huge. I doubt they would work on a single file. If so, how do they handle merging the components?

Comment: JS now supports importing modules. You can even do it on the client side now.

Comment: search for `grunt` and `grunt-contrib-concat` and how to use it. this would be a whole new world for you, but believe me, it would be a milestone.

Comment: note that module importing is not well supported in the browser yet